# Convert array of strings to TypeScript type

Tags: typescript, tsc, typescript3.0

Say I have an array of strings:

```
const s = ['foo', 'rolo', 'zoombaz'];
```

and so I would get:

```
type v = {
   foo: string,
   rolo: string,  
   zoombaz: string
}
```

bonus: Ideally I am looking to map them to camel-case, so if I had:

```
const s = ['foo', 'rolo', 'zoom-baz'];
```

I would get:

```
type v = {
   foo: string,
   rolo: string,  
   zoomBaz: string
}
```

in some cases, I would want to tell it to use boolean instead of string. This is for a command line parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you'll need to get TypeScript to infer the element type of the array as a union of string literal types instead of widening to `string`.  The standard trick supported by the compiler to do this is to run the array through an identity function that infers an element type constrained by `string`:

```
function asLiterals<T extends string>(arr: T[]): T[] { return arr; }
const s = asLiterals(['foo', 'rolo', 'zoombaz']);
```

Now you can define:

```
type v = {[K in (typeof s)[number]]: string};
```

TypeScript won't do any string manipulation such as camel-casing in the type system.  However, you could initially define the names in the casing you want for types and then convert to whatever other casing at runtime.

Comment: thanks, I can't figure out what the `s[number]` is doing?

Comment: This should be parsed as `(typeof s)[number]`; I added parentheses.  Given the type of the array, it gets the type of the array elements.

Comment: yeah I still don't understand the notation what is `[number]` doing?

Comment: `(typeof s)[number]` is an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types) (also known as a lookup type) that gets the type resulting from indexing `typeof s` with an index of type `number`.

Comment: if i do `const myList = ['foo', 'rolo', 'zoombaz'];` and then `const s = asLiterals(myList);`, it doesn't check the types anymore.  what is the difference?