# How to convert array of strings "variable" to typescript types?

Tags: arrays, typescript

I'd like to know how to convert array of string variable to type script types.

Note: There are two SO answers already that deal with this but strings are passed hardcoded to keep values of strings as they are.

- [How to convert array of strings to typescript types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54070785/how-to-convert-array-of-strings-to-typescript-types)
- [Convert array of strings to TypeScript type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52173855/convert-array-of-strings-to-typescript-type)

Both answers pass an array in-line to keep string values in array as literals.
But when you pass an array as a variable, it fails to work.

### Passing values in-line works.

[image: Edit TypeScript - Array to Literal - Hardcode works]
[image: in-line works]

### But passing values as a variable doesn't work

[image: Edit TypeScript - Array to Literal - Doesn't work]
[image]

### Question

So how do you create a type to limit a list of allowable string values in `domElements` as a variable to `asLiterals`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an array literal is assigned to a variable, it is widened to match the typical behavior.

Because of that, the variable `domElements` is of type `string[]` instead of `('a' | 'div' | ...)[]`

The answer is in your own code. Use a similar function as your `asLiterals()` to create a literal array.

```
export function literalArray<T extends KeyTypes>(...entries: T[]): T[] {
    return entries
}
```

You can also find this function in the `type-plus` library.

Comment: Thanks @unional about widened type behavior. I've tried it with `literalArray` after installing `type-plus` but the `DOMType` is still recognized as `string`. https://imgur.com/a/uwQcF8Y. (https://codesandbox.io/s/7j15z1o856) What could I be missing?

Comment: After it is widened, there is no automatically way to narrow it down. I.e, you have to in-line it. Your `domElements` and `arr` are the same. Only type is different.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification . I will in-line the code as a last resort for my library.